# How can I pass my API key through header while making request to Stackoverflow API using python

Tags: python, api-key

```
 headers = {'APIKEY':'----my API key here-----'}

 response =  requests.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?page=1&pagesize=5&order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow',headers=headers)

"quota_max":300,"quota_remaining":299
```

This shows that max quota is 300 but I think I should get max quota of 10000 as mentioned on stackoverflow's API page. Please help me out if I am passing my API key the wrong way, while making the requests. What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you got `APIKEY` from but it should be `access_token`, and it should be a url parameter. Pass `access_token` as a url parameter in a dict instead. You can also include the other parameters in your url.

```
url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users'
params = {'access_token': my_token, 'page': 1, 'pagesize': 5, 
          'order': 'desc', 'sort': 'reputation', 'site': 'stackoverflow'}
response = requests.get(url, params=params)
```

Comment: I was using the wrong term, instead of 'APIKEY' I should've used 'key' and given it the value of my api key. I realised my mistake. Thanks anyway.